# Can I use an airport meditation room as a reading room?

Tags: airports, lounges

Many airports now have repositioned [airport chapels](https://boingboing.net/2018/01/09/whats-the-story-behind-airpo.html) to be multi-faith, or even no-faith meditation rooms.

Does anyone know the rules for these? Can I just sit quietly in a corner and read a book? That ought not to disturb anyone who is meditating, I hope.

I wouldn't want to push it by playing with a phone or eat or generally using it as a lounge area, but would reading be acceptable? Would it matter what I am reading?

This might sound opinion-based, or the rules may vary by airport, so I would like answers from anyone who has ever done so, or asked officials about doing so.

Comment: Quietly reading to oneself without vocalization would seem appropriate to me. This would be especially true if the room is otherwise unused. Certainly anything that would be distracting such as eating or playing with a phone would be totally inappropriate and wrong.

Comment: Well, if you're reading Hustler, someone might say something.

Comment: It would be absurd if in a multi-faith room, people complain about quiet and inoffensive practices different from their own. But if in doubt, put the book in a plain leather cover or similar, and don't cross your legs.

Comment: I use a Kindle anyway, so that's not an issue. I was just wondering that the fact that I am obviously not meditating might lead to problems. I would really like to hear from someone who has experience of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would seem to depend on exactly what type of "airport chapel" you run across as there happen to be a few different types: http://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2015/07/06/most-of-the-busiest-u-s-airports-have-dedicated-chapels/

If it is as you referenced more of an interfaith space, I would say absolutely.

There do also seem to be some more dedicated areas at different hubs. For instance it would not be so appropriate to get Kindle cozy at the Catholic Mass or Jewish or Muslim prayer services.

You should not be concerned regarding not meditating. Especially in the interfaith chapels, I would expect you to encounter all sorts of people and sometimes no one at all. There could easily be a family taking communion, or young people worshiping, people may gather to mourn, or even just to get away from screaming airport kids. There's really no telling.

I would assume they're a lot like the chapels in hospitals, just not quite as somber.